# Fetch contact-form-7 id to another plugin

Tags: wordpress

How to fetch contact-form-7 forms ID, to another plugin??

I want to get forms id and using that id, ill give some effect to that form, please tell me how to fetch form id from contact-form-7, to another plugin in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in contact form 7,the post type is *wpcf7_contact_form*
So you can use this bellow code . In tis code the function return an array of all contact form's id.

```
function get_cf7_IDS(){
   $cf7_id_array =array();
    if ( post_type_exists( 'wpcf7_contact_form' ) ) {
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form',
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
      );
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          $the_query->the_post();
          $cf7_id_array[]= get_the_ID(); 
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
      }   
  }
  return $cf7_id_array; //RETURN THE ARRAY OF IDS
}
```

Then use this function to get all ides in array ***get_cf7_IDS()***.
Then let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: is it possible to fetch Title(Name) also along with ID ?? @Souvik Sikdar

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. i hop it help you

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'wpcf7_contact_form', 'posts_per_page' => -1);
$cf7Forms = get_posts( $args );
foreach($cf7Forms as $f)
{
     // Contact form id 
     echo $f->ID;
}
```